# На Android 7.0 и выше получаю исключение FileUriExposedException при вызове html файла из html в android_asset

Tags: android, html

API приложения:
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 25

В проекте приложения есть файл справки в    `\app\src\main\assets\help\help_ru.html`
Тут же находится файл `\app\src\main\assets\help\WhatsNew_ru.html`

Справка открывается в отдельном активити с помощью
`webView.loadUrl( file:///android_asset/help/help_ru.html );`
В help_ru.html стандартный вызов локального файла
`<a href="WhatsNew_ru.html">Изменения в приложении</a>`

**На андроидах до 7-го при нажатии на "Изменения в приложении" файл WhatsNew_ru.html открывается без проблем, а на 7 и выше приложение падает с исключением:**
`android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///android_asset/help/WhatsNew_ru.html exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`

FileProvider в манифесте объявлен, путь в `\res\xml\filepaths.xml` тоже:
`<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>`
Путь задан для запуска апк на устновку с помощью интента `Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` из `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/appname/files/appname.apk` и работает норамльно на всех целевых андроидах.
Все сделано, как тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/10141625

Весь интернет и форум перерыл, ответа не нашел.
Возможно ли исправить эту ситуацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением в HelpActivity:
`webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
           webView.loadUrl(url);
           return true;
       }
});`